# Integration tests with reference to MS Access Engine on Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, reference, ms-access-2010, azure-pipelines

I have some integration tests and the problem is that they require [Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) to be installed on a machine so in Azure Pipelines tests just fail because cannot find it.

MS Access Engine is needed to create a connection to Excel files and query them.

```
connectionStr = $"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={path};Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 XML;"
```

I need advice how to overcome this problem. There are just a couple of ideas:

- Find some dll that will allow executing tests without Access Engine
  Installed (as I understood this won't work because the Provider
  should be registered in the system)
- Create a VM with MS Access Engine installed (I'd like a simpler solution)
- Set up Azure Pipeline so it will have Access Engine in there...somehow

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to execute tests that require MS Access Engine in
   Azure Pipelines?
2. If yes, what's the easiest/correct way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effective way is to install  Microsoft Access Database Engine on your local machine or VM, and then you can create a [self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops) to run your test that require MS Access Engine.

In azure pipeline, it supports running build on microsoft-hosted agent and self-hosted agent.

Check this doc about the [Microsoft-hosted agent configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#software).

Access Engine is not pre-installed in the microsoft-hosted agent, so the microsoft-hosted agent couldn't meet the test requirements. It may cause the error.

In this situation, the correct method is that you could create a self-hosted agent and run the test on it.